# python value assignment error (whats wrong with 08, 09)

Tags: python

I observed this peculiar behavior while trying to assign a integer value to a variable. What is the possible explanation?

```
>>> a = 01
>>> a = 02
>>> a = 03
>>> a = 04
>>> a = 05
>>> a = 06
>>> a = 07
>>> a = 08
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = 08
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> a = 09
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = 09
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

I'm using python 2.7.6, gcc 4.8.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number starting with 0 is an *octal literal*.

8 is an invalid octal digit, so 08 makes no sense. Ditto 09.

Drop the leading zeros, even if they did make your source code look pretty.

Answer (score 4):

`08` [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) is `10` decimal. Write `010`.

```
01 == 1
02 == 2
# ...
07 == 7
010 == 8
011 == 9
012 == 10
# ...
017 == 15
020 == 16
```

Comment: Ohh... old C notations.

Comment: Every programming language I know uses this notation for octal numbers. What would you do?

Comment: VBA doesn't, out of interest.

Comment: I didn't know that. I did use `hex` numbers a lot but **never** had to deal with octal. And now I know.

Comment: In Python 3 even `01` is invalid. You'll have to use `0o1`.

Comment: @Matthias Thats a better (more explicit) notation. Do you agree?

Comment: I like the explicit approach.